# Using sessions in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, session, blogs

I have a blog site with all the blog stuff including a post page the problem is i'm trying to use a php session to select a table in my database i am kinda a major noob in this but tried `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN']_blog")` this didn't work
so i tried `$user = $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'];
        $blog = _blog;
"mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $user . '' . $blog")` and still nothing any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the ambiguity in the string interpolation, you need to wrap it in braces like this...

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN']}_blog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$userblog = $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'] . '_blog';
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $userblog");
```

Note that it's probably a terrible idea to have one database table per user. The database structure should not depend on dynamic data like that.

Comment: "Note that it's probably a terrible idea to have one database table per user..." What would be something i should look in to that would be a better why to do this?

Comment: @Luke: I'd make one table for users, and one for all blog posts, where each blog post has a `user` field. Then let the database do the querying, which is what you pay it for, and say `SELECT ... WHERE user_id = $id` etc.

Comment: Thank you I'll certainly give this a try.